# How do I get all values for a nested field using elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am able to get all of the values in the database for a text field using an aggregate query in elastic search 6.8:

```
{
  aggs: {
    values: {
      terms: { field: 'City.keyword', size: 200 },
    },
  },
  size: 0,
};
```

I am trying to do the same thing for nested field.

Below is an example of a text field (City) and a nested field (Cooling)

```
"City": "Fredericksburg",
"Cooling": [
    {
        "key": "Fuel",
        "value": "Electric"
    },
    {
        "key": "Central Air",
        "value": "Y"
    },
    {
        "key": "Central A/C",
        "value": "true"
    }
],
```

And here's the documentation I've been referencing:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

Here is the relevant mapping:

```
{
  "listings:366": {
    "mappings": {
      "_default_": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
          ...
          {
            "Cooling": {
              "path_match": "Cooling.*",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          ...
        ],
        "properties": {
          ...
          "Cooling": {
            "type": "nested"
          },
          ...
        }
      },
      "listings": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
          ...
          {
            "Cooling": {
              "path_match": "Cooling.*",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          ...
        ],
        "properties": {
          ...
          "Cooling": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "key": {
                "type": "text"
              },
              "value": {
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Cooling` is of `nested` type, then you can achieve what you want by nesting the `terms` aggregation in a [top-level `nested` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html) first in order to "dive into" the Cooling nested documents:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "cooling": {
      "nested": {
        "path": " Cooling"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "values": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "Cooling.key",  <--- make sure this field is mapped as keyword
            "size": 200
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Your mapping needs to change to this:

```
    "properties": {
      ...
      "Cooling": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "key": {
            "type": "keyword"       <--- change this
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks correct but it is still returning zero buckets in the buckets array.

Comment: Can you update your question with the real mapping of your index, please, using `GET your-index-name` ?

Comment: I added the relevant mapping, hoping that's what you were looking for.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that `Cooling.key` should be matched as `keyword` instead of `text`, otherwise aggregations won't work

Comment: I get the error "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [Cooling.key] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead." I had previously gotten that error with the text field aggregation which is why I started using City.keyword. I'm guessing that won't work here?

Comment: Re-read my comment, please. Your field is of type `text` and it needs to be of type `keyword` otherwise it won't work. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

try to use composite aggregation :
see [composite Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried the examples listed in that section of the documentation already but can't get them to return anything but empty buckets. Could you provide an example using the scenario I've provided?